# How do I improve this questions?

Tags: discussion

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/72679/which-one-is-the-correct-way-to-put-seatbelt-on-busty-women?noredirect=1#comment131141_72679

I think what I want to ask is not which way to put it "legal".

What I want to ask is when the car crash, which way to put the seatbelt would save the woman's spinal cord.

I think 1 is unsafe.

I think 2 could damage her baloon.

But hey, I need expert opinions.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question was rejected because it wasn't about biology. You could try on another stack but I can't see any way to improve it that would make it on-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

We are not experts on automobile safety. Perhaps try over at [Health](https://health.stackexchange.com/), but all in all I don't understand the point of this question. What is a baloon? If it has to do with breasts then I don't understand its relation to the spinal cord. In turn, why would safety belts be dangerous for your spinal cord? Lastly and obviously the correct answer is 'C' as indeed in a frontal car crash your breasts will become seriously injured when putting the belt as in A, while in B the belt's going to cut into your chest. It should be fitted with the broad site towards you, again quite obviously.

To be honest, I thought the linked question was to troll around. Was it?

Comment: Alice, what you did, is a very good answer